# Application Insights does not pickup Instrumentation Key from ApplicationInsights.config

Tags: c#, logging, config, azure-application-insights, telemetry

No matter what I try, Application Insights in a simple C# Console App (NetCORE) will not pickup the InstrumentationKey. I am using the following code:

```
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
Console.WriteLine("Key=" + telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey);
```

And the following ApplicationInsights.config file:

```
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <InstrumentationKey>1234</InstrumentationKey>
  <!--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config#instrumentationkey-->
</ApplicationInsights>
```

The key is always empty.

I have tried wrapping the config contents in  and I have tried removing the  tag. I have tried the following code too:

```
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault());
Console.WriteLine("Key=" + telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey);
```

My previous question on the subject resulted in a solution that required the ApplicationInsights.config file to exist in the project folder for the debug application insights logger to work correctly. Link: [Unable to get Application Insights to show debugging telemetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58307327/unable-to-get-application-insights-to-show-debugging-telemetry/58311281#58311281) . One of the users notes that NetCORE is no longer using that config file, yet I find that hard to believe as otherwise no telemetry is logged in the debug Application Insights 
 Telemetry.

The documentation for it does not mention InstrumentationKey inside of the config file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config#instrumentationkey

Is there a way to just run those two lines of code and have it pick up the instrumentation key from the config file or do I have to set it up manually in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET Core or ASP.NET Core projects SDK does not read applicationinsights.config file.
For console apps, the recommended approach is documented here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#net-corenet-framework-console-application).
Instrumentation key is specified in appsettings.json in those cases.

Comment: I see. I find it weird then that it requires ApplicationInsights.config to track Telemetry using the VS Application Insights logging tool for debug sessions, as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58307327/unable-to-get-application-insights-to-show-debugging-telemetry/58311281#58311281 .